# Simulate a sample function with known power spectrum

Tags: fourier-analysis, spherical-harmonics

There is a known power spectrum $$C_l=\frac1{2l+1}\sum_{m=-l}^l |a_{lm}|^2$$ for some $l=0,1,\dots,l_{max}$ where $$
a_{lm}=\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \mathrm \int_0^{2\pi}f(\theta,\phi)Y^*_{lm}(\theta,\phi)\,d\phi\,d\theta$$
are got using complex spherical harmonics for an unknown real function $f$. Is there a way to "restore" such a sample function $f$?

The problem is that besides $f$ is represented as $$f(\theta,\phi)=\sum_{l=0}^{l_{max}}\sum_{m=-l}^l a_{lm}Y_{lm}(\theta,\phi),$$ taking arbitrary complex $a_{lm}$ with known sums of absolute values for each $l$ could produce a complex $f$ while a real function is required.

Is there a property of $a_{lm}$ coefficients for real $f$ or some condition on $a_{lm}$ that guarantee $f$ to be real?

UPD. Using real spherical harmonics could be a solution, but they probably produce a different power spectrum. So, the task could be solved if there is any relation between the real and complex power spectra.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, are you applying this to any field in particular? e.g. In astroph there are packages that solve this problem (cmbfast)

Comment: You can generate such a function by drawing random numbers $a_{lm}$ from a gaussian with mean $0$ and variance $C_l$ (using a Box-Cox transform this can be done only generating random numbers from a uniform distribution).

Comment: @caverac, doesn't cmbfast like CAMB solve the opposite problem? Calculate power spectra for some model cmb anisotropy?

Comment: @Winther, but real $a_{lm}$ would't give real $f$, should I generate complex gaussian somehow?

Comment: You can draw the norm $r$ ($a_{lm} = re^{i\theta}$) from a Raylight distribution (draw a uniform number $U$ in $[0,1]$ and set the norm to be $\sqrt{-\log(U)C_l}$) and draw the phase $\theta$ from a uniform distribution on $[0,2\pi]$ if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Winther, thank you, but sorry, I can't catch why $f$ would be at least approximately real? Here we have something like $\sum_{m=-l}^{l} K_{lm}(\theta,\phi)e^{i(\theta_m+\phi)}$ for each $l$ ($\theta_m$ is the random one), and there is no way to pass to a limit $m\to\infty$.

Comment: From the definition of $a_{lm}$ take the complex conjugate and use that $f$ is real and $Y_{l,m}^* = (-1)^mY_{l,-m}$ to get something like $a_{lm}^* = (-1)^ma_{l,-m}$ (so you would only draw for $m\geq 0$ and let the other values be determined by this condition). But it's a long time since I worked with this so I'll have to double check what I said above is correct.

Comment: @Winther OK, thank you. I'll try it out. Now I see, the $Y_{lm}$ relies on $m$-th derivative of $P_l$ and $m$ could not be negative here. So there should be some relation between $Y_{l,m}$ and $Y_{l,-m}$ and this could be used to zero down the imaginary part of the sum above.